# get tally data by company wise using ado.net

Tags: c#, ado.net, tally, cdata-drivers

I am having 3 companies in my tally . I am getting the data from tally using cData ADO.Net Provider. Now, I can get only Selected company data from tally.  But I want to get all the selected company data for example if 2 companies are showing in the list. I want to get that 2 companies data and also I want to get that tally data as companies wise. Please help me in this case. Are there Possibilities for this. Can any one help for this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Check Out This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67135837/13605609)
Use SVCURRENTCOMPANY Tag as shown in