# Is there any solution for inserting data into multiple companies in tally ERP 9 at time?

Tags: tally

I have 5 companies in my Tally ERP9 and I am trying to Push data into multiple companies in tally at same time. The data is linked based on the company name. But the data gets inserted for only selected company. How can i insert data in multiple companies at a time. Please help

Comment: Anyone who is a expert in web to tally integration please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add **SVCURRENTCOMPANY** Tag in Static Variables

No matter Company is selected or not data will go to that company

```
.....
<STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>ABC Company</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
</STATICVARIABLES>
.....
```

**Replace ABC Company with your desired company name**